# Specify exact StringBuilder capacity or use default?

Tags: java, string, performance, stringbuilder, capacity

I have a method in which I have input URL as String and I have to remove a suffix from it and to add another. For that reason I use StringBuilder, but I am wondering do I have to specify the exact **capacity** of the *Builder* or to rely on the default value **16** which will not be enough in all of my cases, so the capacity will expand in the code always.?

My code is like this:

```
private String constructString(final String url, final String suffixToRemove, final String suffixToAdd) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(url.length() - suffixToRemove.length() + suffixToAdd.length());
        .....
    }
```

I want to determine if it will be faster to put the default capacity of the Builder or to put the exact capacity constructed by getting `.length` of three strings. Is `String.length` a slow operation?

Comment: Sounds like a micro-optimisation to me. Unless you're going to be putting a *huge* amount of text into the `StringBuilder`, I wouldn't bother setting it's initial size at all.

Comment: Yes it is micro optimization. And I was wondering which is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
final int len = url.length() - suffixToRemove.length();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
sb.setLength(len);
return sb.append(suffixToAdd).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for large texts it avoids repeated increases. For small strings it could do to use a size that is both small enough, and seldom needs an increase. but evaluating an integer expression, with several `.length()` certainly overshoots the target, and might even be slower, than say 80 (default is 16 I believe).

Micro-optimization and disruptive to reading the code.